# Question about Hall's 2015 book on Lie groups and Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

On page 14 Hall writes that a $2n\times 2n$ unitary matrix $U$ is "quaternion linear" as it commutes with the operators $\mathbf i,J,\mathbf iJ$. I don't understand what he means by "quaternion linear". Also in Wikipedia ["Symplectic group"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) it is written that $Sp(n)$ contains $n\times n$ quaternionic matrices which preserves the norm. How exactly can a $2n\times 2n$ complex "quaternion linear" matrix be expressed as an $n\times n$ quaternionic matrix. I suspect that $U$ has the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
-\overline B & \overline A
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A,B$ are $n\times n$ complex matrices, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: You can identify $\Bbb C^{2n}$ with $\Bbb H^n$ in a natural way. This second space has the structure of a quaternion left module. The statement the author is making is that U(2n) matrixes are linear in the sense that $U h v= hUv$ for $U \in U(2n), h\in \Bbb H,  v\in \Bbb H^n$.

Comment: @s.harp Does $U$ has the form of the matrix I mentioned in the last part of my question? If yes, how to prove that? If not, why not?

Comment: $U$ should be one of those unitaries that commute with the $J$, these are all of the form you indicate. To get the condition calculate the expression $U(J(x,0))= J(U(x,0))$ in dependence of $A,B,C,D$ where $U=\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\ C&D\end{pmatrix}$.